# Searching custom fields is removing search on the post_title column

Tags: search, admin

I have the following custom search active in our WP admin for only administrators

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'query_custom_admin_search', 21  );
function query_custom_admin_search( $wp_query ) {
    global $current_user;

    if( is_admin() ) {
        if (get_current_user_role()=="administrator"){
            if ( $wp_query->query['post_type'] != "apartments" ){
                return;
            }else{
                $custom_fields = array("city","state_county",);
                $search_term = $wp_query->query_vars['s'];
                
                if ( $search_term != '' ) {
                    $meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );
                    foreach( $custom_fields as $custom_field ) {
                        array_push( $meta_query, array(
                            'key' => $custom_field,
                            'value' => $search_term,
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        ));
                    }
                    $wp_query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
                };

                return;
            }
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
```

This searches custom meta keys that we need to check and it works great.   The only problem is that the default search columns in the wp_posts table such as post_title seem to no longer be searched.

How can I do both in this query ?

Comment: I remembered having answered a similar question in the past, and the solution was to use a custom `WHERE` condition if I'm not mistaken. So the query would be like `WHERE ( <meta query> OR <search query> )` - that's what you're trying to do, right?

Comment: And is there a specific reason you didn't create the `city` and `state_county` as custom taxonomies instead? Because taxonomy is the better approach for categorizing posts, or grouping posts together.

Comment: The custom fields I need were created by the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, that is why the search extends in this way.    Do you have reference to that other question you answered ?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The only problem is that the default search columns in the wp_posts
> table such as post_title seem to no longer be searched.

They're actually being searched, but the operator used is `AND` instead of `OR` as in `WHERE ( <search query> AND <meta query> )`, hence if for example one searched for `foo`, then WordPress will search for posts which..

- Contain `foo` in the post title/content/excerpt *and*
- Contain `foo` in the meta `city` or `state_county`

So if you want the operator be changed to `OR`, i.e. search in the post title/content/excerpt **or** your custom fields, then you can try the following which simply repositions the default search query in the `WHERE` clause:

1. This snippet modifies the meta queries (to add your custom fields) and also sets a private arg used as a flag which if true, then we'll reposition the search query.

   ```php
   add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'query_custom_admin_search', 21 );
   function query_custom_admin_search( $query ) {
       // Check if the current user has the 'administrator' role.
       if ( ! in_array( 'administrator', (array) wp_get_current_user()->roles ) ) {
           return;
       }

       // Check if we're on the "Posts" page at wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=apartments
       // and that a search keyword is set.
       if ( ! is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query()     ||
           'edit-apartments' !== get_current_screen()->id ||
           ! strlen( $query->get( 's' ) )
       ) {
           return;
       }

       // Retrieve existing meta queries, if any.
       $meta_query = (array) $query->get( 'meta_query' );

       // Define your custom fields (meta keys).
       $custom_fields = array( 'city', 'state_county' );
       // This is for your custom fields above.
       $meta_query2   = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );

       $s = $query->get( 's' );
       foreach ( $custom_fields as $meta_key ) {
           $meta_query2[] = array(
               'key'     => $meta_key,
               'value'   => $s,
               'compare' => 'LIKE',
           );
       }

       // Add your meta query to the existing ones in $meta_query.
       $meta_query[] = $meta_query2;
       $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

       // Set a custom flag for the posts_search and posts_where.
       $query->set( '_search_OR', true );
   }
   ```
2. This snippet uses the [`posts_search` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_search/) to "empty" the search query, after storing it in a private arg which we'll use in the [`posts_where` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_where/) where we reposition the search query.

   ```php
   add_filter( 'posts_search', 'wpse_401476_admin_posts_search', 21, 2 );
   function wpse_401476_admin_posts_search( $search, $query ) {
       if ( $query->get( '_search_OR' ) ) {
           $query->set( '_search_SQL', $search );
           $search = '';
       }

       return $search;
   }
   ```
3. Now this snippet is the one that repositions the search query. It uses [`WP_Meta_Query::get_sql()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/get_sql/) to retrieve the meta query's (SQL) clauses (`join` and `where`) used in the current query.

   ```php
   add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse_401476_admin_posts_where', 21, 2 );
   function wpse_401476_admin_posts_where( $where, $query ) {
       if ( $query->get( '_search_OR' ) &&
           $search = $query->get( '_search_SQL' )
       ) {
           global $wpdb;

           $clauses = $query->meta_query->get_sql( 'post', $wpdb->posts, 'ID', $query );

           if ( ! empty( $clauses['where'] ) ) {
               $where2 = "( 1 $search ) OR ( 1 {$clauses['where']} )";
               $where  = str_replace( $clauses['where'], " AND ( $where2 )", $where );

               $query->set( '_search_SQL', false );
               $query->set( '_search_OR', false );
           }
       }

       return $where;
   }
   ```

   So with the above, we'd get a condition that looks like `( ( 1 AND <search query> ) OR ( 1 AND <meta query> ) )` which is equivalent to the `( <search query> OR <meta query> )`.

Tried & tested working on WordPress v5.8.3.

### Notes:

1. Use the above snippets instead of what you have in the question.
2. The operator would only be changed if the current user has the `administrator` *role* and that the current page is the admin page for managing posts in the `apartments` post type, and that the search keyword is set, and I also checked if the current query/`WP_Query` is the *main* query.
3. I used `21` as the priority, hence you might want to use a greater number (e.g. `100`) to make the filters apply properly (i.e. not overwritten by plugins or the active theme).

Comment: Amazing Sally CJ thanks so much!   This is a really good basis for what I need.   This is a really good reference for others I hope.

Comment: I'm glad I wasn't mistaken that you indeed wanted to change the `AND` to `OR` 

Comment: However, the reason I initially asked why didn't you use custom taxonomies/terms instead, is because unlike taxonomies/terms, meta *values* are not [indexed](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/mysql-query-optimization-using-indexes-with-examples/) and thus meta queries like in your (and the above) code, which finds posts by specific meta values, can cause your site to run (extremely) slow when the site becomes large(r). So please consider using taxonomy queries instead.

Comment: The `AND` search, however, also applies even when doing taxonomy queries (i.e. WordPress would do `WHERE <search query> AND <taxonomy query>`), and unfortunately, changing the `AND` wouldn't be as simple as repositioning the search query.. (you would have to manually construct the taxonomy query's SQL).

Answer (score 0):

try to return the $wp_query when is not admin

```php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'query_custom_admin_search', 21  );
function query_custom_admin_search( $wp_query ) {
    global $current_user;
    if (current_user_can('administrator' && is_admin()){
        if ( $wp_query->query['post_type'] != "apartments" ){
            return;
        }else{
            $custom_fields = array("city","state_county",);
            $search_term = $wp_query->query_vars['s'];
            if ( $search_term != '' ) {
                $meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );
                foreach( $custom_fields as $custom_field ) {
                    array_push( $meta_query, array(
                        'key' => $custom_field,
                        'value' => $search_term,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ));
                }
                $wp_query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
            }
            return;
        }
    }else{
        return $wp_query;
    }
}
```